# parse number from formatted number string

Tags: d3.js

I'm formatting a number using d3.format('.2s'). Such numbers are displayed on draggable handles at either end of a numeric range.

The problem is that the exact pixel the user "drops" the handle might translate to a value of 51,235. But the handle will show 51k. I would like the filter to be applied at 51,000, i.e. it should match the handle. So either the handle needs to be "sticky" or I need to parse the rounded number - and I'm aiming for the second option.

I have several numeric filters, some running 0-400 and others 0-10M or 0-100%. They are drawn dynamically. So I'd like to read the handle value of e.g. '51k' and convert it back into a number of 51000. I have to use d3 v3 as I'm using dc.js and crossfilter in parts of the page. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem... if you don't want SI prefixes, simply don't use SI prefixes.

Comment: I think you are looking for something described in here: [*"Is there a “reverse” function for d3.format?"*](/q/43459912)

Comment: @Gerardo - I do want to use the SI prefix. Subsequently, I want to parse the number from the SI prefix. So if 51,234 with a format of 's' gives me 51k, I want to parse 51000 from that. I can't do a manual rounding on 51,234 because I don't know what kind of number I'll have.

Comment: @altocumulus - thank you, yes I want a reverse function. Unfortunately none of those listed include the 's' format, which applies strings to the number and isn't just a numerical transformation. e.g. 10000000 --> 10M

Comment: @emma If you use exactly that `reverse()` function from the answer I linked to this will give `reverse("51k") === 51000`. What other do you want? https://jsfiddle.net/7uj1m34r/

Comment: yes you are right! Thank you! I couldn't see an 's' option in the transformation object so I thought it was for other formats. That's brilliant, thank you!